# How does internaly git compose files so quick (just "academic" question)

Tags: git, theory

I have just "academic" question for Git experts.

I could not find anything about how Git actually internaly compose files from all the commits.
I could not imagine that it iterate through all commits untill ***now*** (go from the very first commit and keep changing/adding/deleting etc. until it have current version).

Wouldn't it be slow for large codebases with *MANY* commits, many big files etc.? But maybe I am imagine it wrong.
Maybe it do the work once in a while and save the "complete picture" after some commits to keep the "composing" fast, so it doesn't need to start from the very beginning, I dont know :) ... something like 'memoization'.

Has anybody here better understanding of what is going on internally in Git when it figuring out ***current files***?

Comment: Nope. Git saves full files (in a compressed format). Check https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: so.... just to wrap up what I should have said: git uses the revision object that you point to to find out the trees and blobs that make it up and given that all objects are kept in full in its DB, it's (kind of) _trivial_ to get back the contents of each one (either to checkout, diff, etc etc etc).

Comment: Yes, that's the snapshot-based storage model vs the changeset-based one. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software).

Comment: Every commit has the "complete picture". Git stores every complete picture in an efficient manner to prevent duplication. An overview can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F).

Comment: You might also read chapter 1 of my (currently moribund) [book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).